# Edit userPropfile asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I have this:

Controller action:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
 {
      UserProfile user = db.SelectByID(id);
      return View(user);
      //if (id == null)
      //{
      //    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      //}
      //UserProfile userProfile = db.SelectByID(id);
      //if (userProfile == null)
      //{
      //    return HttpNotFound();
      //}
      //return View(userProfile);
      }
```

ModelView:

```
 [Table("UserProfile")]
 public class UserProfile
 {
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
  }
```

And the view:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Account"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Lola Biker</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

It is an asp.net mvc4 application and I want to edit the firstName and LastName of the registered user. I add some extra properties to the Register user. But If I run the application I get this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 221:            {
Line 222:
Line 223:                UserProfile user = db.SelectByID(id);
Line 224:                return View(user);
Line 225:                //if (id == null)

Source File: g:\Mijn Documents\My Web Sites\Lolabikes\C#\ContosoUniversity\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Line: 223
```

I am logged in and will be redirected to the edit page like this:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <text>
        Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Edit", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
    </text>
}
else
{
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Thank you for your help

I als tried like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    UserProfile user = db.SelectByID(id);
    return View(user);
}
```

but then I still get id = null

I have my Edit now like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    UserProfile user = db.SelectByID(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(user);               
}
```

and view:

```
@Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Edit", "Account", new { userId = 123 }, new { title = "Manage" })
```

I put breakpoint on this:   if (id == null)

and it says: null = null

I have the Edit now like this:

public ActionResult Edit(int? userId)
            {

```
            //if (userId = null )
            //{
            //    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            //}
             UserProfile user = db.SelectByID(userId);
     //       if (user == null)
     //       {
     //           return HttpNotFound();
     //       }
            return View(user);               
        }
```

but user is null

so If I do it like this , what you suggest:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int userId )
 {
    //your code here you get the userId to manipulate.
 }
```

ofcourse I see then empty texboxes(firstName, lastName)

ok, I have it now like this:

@Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Edit", "Account", new { Id= Context.User.Identity.Name  }, new { title = "Manage" })

and a model UserProfile, like this:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        //ok
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

But my Id is ofcourse a integer, also in the datbase. but this:

Id= Context.User.Identity.Name - Identity.Name - I only see Name - that is a string, how to change that??

because:  UserProfile user = db.SelectByID(Id); still user is null????

Thank you

Comment: are you sending the id of the user?

Comment: what do you mean? I have edit my post

Comment: show the code where u r clicking "Edit"

Comment: it is here  Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Edit", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!

Comment: see you are not passing the userid, so its taking 0 bydefault

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

let me know anything else is required

Comment: But how to pass tthe username in there? Thank you

Comment: I try like this:   Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Edit", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = Item.ID , title = "Manage" })!

Comment: But that doesnt work

Comment: Id= Context.User.Identity.Name is your problem? ok now is the user name(usually email id's) unique in your entire application? if so using this name retrieve the Id of the user from DB. If the name is not unique then in your application where ever you are setting the user context add on his Id also, So that you can access it like 
Id= Context.User.Identity.Id

Comment: the problem is this: UserProfile user = db.SelectByID(Id); user is still null

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Edit", "Account", new { userId = *Your ID here* }, new {title = "Manage"})
```

and your controller method like

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int userId )
 {
    //your code here you get the userId to manipulate.
 }
```

the mistake you are doing is you are providing null for the route values. Which is why you are getting null in your controller action.

Comment: I triied that, but the problem is I get an error on Item: Error 4 The name 'Item' does not exist in the current context g:\Mijn Documents\My Web Sites\Lolabikes\C#\ContosoUniversity\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml 4 80 Lolabike

Comment: this error is because there is no object called Item in your view page. I guess you are new to MVC. now remove the Item.ID and hardcode a number like `new { userId = 123 }` and try, Tel me what happens

Comment: it still says:null = null

Comment: where do you see null? controller or view?

Comment: In the contoller: public ActionResult Edit(int? id)

Comment: change your controller as I have told in the answer know :)

Comment: because you are setting the userId = some value in your view your controller action will bind that value only if its parameter is named the same as in the view. In your case as I have suggested it must be `public ActionResult Edit(int? userId)`

Comment: I have a user in the db, like this: 13 hallo101 Margaret Ozerova niels.fischereinie@gmail.com

Comment: UserProfile user = db.SelectByID(userId); is null?? how can that be? I added the userProfile in the context:   public DbSet<UserProfile> userProfiles { get; set; }

Comment: Hi Reddy, what is ur email, then I can sent u the project, my email is: niels.fischereinie@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found a workaround, but it is not ideal, because I am using a Generic repository, but for edit profile, I dont use the repository, this is how I fixed:

```
private LolaBikeContext db = new LolaBikeContext();



public ActionResult Edit(string UserId)
            {             

                string username = User.Identity.Name;

                // Fetch the userprofile
                UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                // Construct the viewmodel
                UserProfile model = new UserProfile();
                model.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                model.LastName = user.LastName;
                model.Email = user.Email;
                model.Motto = user.Motto;
                model.PlaceOfBirth = user.PlaceOfBirth;
                model.HowManyBikes = user.HowManyBikes;
                model.BesideYourBeth = user.BesideYourBeth;
                model.NicestRide = user.NicestRide;
                model.WorstRide = user.WorstRide;
                model.AmountKmPerYear = user.AmountKmPerYear;
                model.AverageSpeed = user.AverageSpeed;
                model.AbleToChatWhileRiding = user.AbleToChatWhileRiding;
                model.PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;




                return View(user);               
            }


            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile userprofile)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string username = User.Identity.Name;
                    // Get the userprofile
                    UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                    // Update fields
                    user.FirstName = userprofile.FirstName;
                    user.LastName = userprofile.LastName;
                    user.Email = userprofile.Email;
                    user.Motto = userprofile.Motto;

                    user.PlaceOfBirth = userprofile.PlaceOfBirth;
                    user.HowManyBikes = userprofile.HowManyBikes;
                    user.BesideYourBeth = userprofile.BesideYourBeth;
                    user.NicestRide = userprofile.NicestRide;
                    user.WorstRide = userprofile.WorstRide;
                    user.AmountKmPerYear = userprofile.AmountKmPerYear;
                    user.AverageSpeed = userprofile.AverageSpeed;
                    user.AbleToChatWhileRiding = userprofile.AbleToChatWhileRiding;
                    user.PhoneNumber = userprofile.PhoneNumber;

                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Account"); // or whatever
                }

                return View(userprofile);
            }
```

So it is not ideal ofcourse , but for now it works

Comment: In your first ActionResult Edit (GET) - why do you map a UserProfile user to another UserProfile model? you are not doing nothing with model so..

Comment: You mean this?  UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

Comment: I meant all of the code under your comment // Construct the view model - is unnecessary as what you end up passing is the object labeled user not the object labeled model

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Edit", "Account", new { userId = *Your ID here* }, new {title = "Manage"})
```

and your controller method like

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(int userId = 0)
 {
    //your code here you get the userId to manipulate.
 }
```